# Oracle BD error al executar el procedimiento almacenado

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
create or replace procedure incremento_xenofobia (salario in number,ciudad in varchar2,r out number) is

begin
    if (ciudad = 'San Francisco') then
        r:=(salario*1.02);
    elsif (ciudad = 'Seattle') then
        r:=(salario*1.05);
    elsif (ciudad = 'Oxford') then
        r:=(salario*1.07);
    else
        r:=salario;
    end if;
end;
```

aqui termina la creacion del procedimiento y empieza el bloque anonimo

```
declare
    cod number:=110;
    sal_a number:=0;
    sal_n number:=0;
    ciu varchar2(50):='';
begin 
   select l.city into ciu
          from employees e 
          inner join departments d on e.department_id=d.department_id
          inner join locations l on l.location_id=d.location_id
          where e.employee_id=cod;
   
   select e.salary into sal_a
          from employees e 
          inner join departments d on e.department_id=d.department_id
          inner join locations l on l.location_id=d.location_id
          where e.employee_id=cod;       
                                            
    execute INCREMENTO_XENOFOBIA(sal_a,ciu,sal_n);
   
    dbms_output.put_line('Salario Anterior: ');
    dbms_output.put_line(sal_a);
    dbms_output.put_line('Salario Nuevo: ');
    dbms_output.put_line(sal_n);
end;
```

lo he probando linea por linea ,el error es al llamar el procedimiento , **las consultas estan correctas.**
no encuentro la falla al momento de excutar y  ya me tiene frustrado eso.

Comment: Pon en el título _cuál es el error_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: ¿y cuál es el mensaje de error?

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de un bloque anónimo no se puede usar el comando "execute".

Como el procedimiento "incremento_xenofobia" ya está compilado, entonces solo es llamarlo por su nombre.